# How to handle Wordpress Http error while uploading images

Tags: wordpress, http

Sometimes I faced the HTTP error on WordPress for different tasks. especially when I try to upload some files in the media library. Some easily uploaded while some give HTTP error. Let me know if you are also facing the same issue. By the way, you can visit [my website](https://birdfeederist.com/) and tell me if there is any issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upload the same file again after some time? I see it's not a permanent error so it may be a server resources problem.

I found this article on the issue, maybe you'll find it helpful:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-http-image-upload-error-in-wordpress/

I'd recommend you to also contact your hosting provider and tell them about the issue.